# Video.js fails to play if video is in browser cache on Chrome for OS X

Tags: javascript, video.js

The problem is intermittent, but video.js is failing to load and play mp4's that have been cached in Chrome for OS X.  Here's what I know so far:

- Disable cache (while DevTools is open) allows the video to play 100% of the time on reload
- If caching is not disabled, and cache is manually cleared the problem still happens
- Closing and restarting Chrome will resolve the problem until the next page refresh
- Appending a ?nocache=20131028-084318 to the source url does not resolve the problem.
- Watching HTTP request using Charles Proxy, I see that on successful runs an HTTP request goes out to Brightcove (my video host).  On failed refreshes, the request never happens.
- On successful runs the sequence of VideoJS events:

  - loadstart
  - durationchange
  - loadedmetadata
  - loadeddata
- On fails:

  - loadstart
- I've tried a variety of ways of setting up the video element, including one noted here, [Video.js Stalling during file load on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090890/video-js-stalling-during-file-load-on-ios)
  and even the most basic setup noted here, https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/setup.md  The latter seems to work better; however, once the browser gets into a bad state clearing the cache and restarting the browser is required.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem and I solved it by disabling the cache to the javaScript file that contains the videojs instance options.

Add this line to your main page at the head

```
<script>document.write('<script src="vid.js?dev=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + '"\><\/script>');</script>
```

Note: vid.js is the file that I put the settings in..

Another solution that I didn't try, but I think it might work, is by adding the JavaScript of the settings in jQuery (ready function).

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue but in Chrome for Windows. I first noticed that it would only load when dev tools is open then I saw your question and realized the dev tools was bypassing caching.

Answer (score 0):

If a user visits the page (on some browsers ie: Safari 6.1, etc...) the video will play the first time. If the user reloads the page by clicking in the address bar and hitting the 'ENTER' key, the video will not fire off it's LOADED/READY (or any other) events on the page 'reload'. This behavior does not happen if the user refreshes the page with the REFRESH button or REFRESH key combo (generally).

I bypassed my Brightcove player issues by dynamically loading the player on the page so it CANNOT be cached.

I also cache busted the Brightcove JS file for good measure.

Load player dynamically with this code:
http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/dynamically-loading-player-using-javascript

Just some opinionated advice. Stay away form Brightcove whenever possible. My peers and I run into LOTS of bugs in their player as well as radically poor documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is specific to video.js. I am able to reproduce this problem by setting up a vanilla html5 video tag. It definitely looks to be related to some caching issue.

Currently, I am able to circumvent the problem by attaching a guid as a query parameter to  the video url to ensure Chrome thinks this is a new video request. I do think there is a Chrome bug out there that needs to be addressed.

I Just found a ticket that matches what I can reproduce:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=234779